# How To Debug Tradingview Indicator?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I am having a hard time figuring out what is wrong with an indicator I am developing. I can't post the code because it is proprietary stuff, but I would like know if it is possible to have an output like the
"journal" and "expert" tab of metatrader, which shows us when there is something wrong with the indicator, even the lines of code with problems.

The indicator I am developing is supposed to draw lines and boxes, and it works properly for the first 100 candles or so, then it stops working properly. It keeps printing some lines and boxes, but stops printing others it was supposed to.

I needed something that could show me a log or live log of what the indicator is doing, and errors that might have happened along the way from past to present.

Answer (score 0):

You can try some of the debugging methods explained [here](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/Debugging.html#compound-conditions).

The most common ones are using `plotchar()` and a `table`.